# Changes in the pre vs. post-treatment behavior of control group

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, time-series, hypothesis-testing

I have survey data that tracks self-reported emotions at the individual-level for observations in two groups  before and after a targeted cash distribution program is introduced. The measure of interest is a categorical variable dividing emotions into: positive, neutral, or negative. I am interested in testing whether the self-reported emotions, particularly negative emotions, change for the treatment group once they receive a randomized cash distribution program, relative to the control group

The daily average monthly pre-treatment share of negative emotions amongst the two groups as is follows, where the two groups have a relative similar share of reported negative emotions:

```
emotion      average_share   group
negative     70%             treatment
negative     69%             control
```

The post-treatment shows a noticeable decline in the share of negative self-reported posts amongst the treatment group (i.e. declining from 70% to a monthly average of 62%) and it's statistically significant at the 0.05 p-value level. However, one concern I have is that the control group's share of negative emotions rises post-treatment, which might be because some individuals in our survey were aware that we randomized the cash distribution program and were thus frustrated for not receiving a cash benefit like their treatment group counterparts. I wonder if this concern would make the control group invalid in this case, i.e. assuming that the two groups are otherwise similar in their characteristics.

```
emotion      average_share   group
negative     62%             treatment
negative     73%             control
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a randomized experiment for estimating the causal effect of assignment **and knowing the assignment** to the two groups, comparing the post-intervention proportions taking into account the pre-intervention state seems fine. Of course, you do not get a direct randomized answer to the question of the effect of doing the intervention versus not doing it when people did not know that an intervention was an option. However, to figure out whether the answer to that question would be different, a different design would help that prevents the effect you speculate about.

Comment: Great response! So essentially we cannot attribute any causal effects we find to the treatment as we are also capturing the impact of control group individuals knowing about assignment, correct?

Comment: I guess you could try all sorts of things like asking people whether this influenced their rating, why they gave ratings etc., which might help you conclude something, but it would rely on people accurately judging what they might have said without the influence and various  other limitations.